# Listening background sounds and converting them into text

Tags: flutter

I am searching for an extension that can automatically recognize and convert background sounds into text on flutter. With this extension, I aim to transcribe conversations or other audio sounds into written text. I vaguely remember hearing about such an extension before, but I couldn't find it. How can I accomplish this task? Do you have any suggestions or recommendations? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The two most used packages to do text to speech are :

- https://pub.dev/packages/google_speech
- https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text

I let you read their documentation and ask a new question if you have issue working with them.

Comment: i tried speech_to_text but it is not working good on android beacuse it is stopping record when u stop speaking for even 1 second.